# Custom list of things in LaTeX?

Tags: latex

I'm writing a script for college where I insert the date of a part of text apart from the chapters using a custom command (currently just displaying a `marginpar`), like:

```
\lesson{1}
\section{A}
\section{B}
\subsection{C}
\lesson{2}
\subsection{D}
```

Apart from the usual `\listoffigures`, `\listoftables` and `\tableofcontents` I want a list that allows access by lesson number. It should look like the `\listoffigures` except with a custom label (since the lessons don't have captions), for example:

```
Lesson 1 ..... Page 1
Lesson 2 ..... Page 5
```

Is there a package that allows me to define new lists like that as easy as creating new counters? Or do I have to dig into the source for the existing lists and hack my own?

(the `memoir` package documentation has a list of rendered examples at the beginning, that would be another example of a custom list like I need it)

Any keywords to google for are appreciated!

Comment: Try http://tex.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do the following:

1) Open a file at the beginning:

```
\newwrite\listoffoo
\immediate\openout\listoffoo=\jobname.foo
```

2) Each command like `\lesson` should put a line into the file:

```
\newcounter{lesson}
\def\lesson{%
    ...
    \refstepcounter{lesson}%
    \immediate\write\listoffoo{%
        \string\lessonfooline{\ref{lesson}}{\pageref{lesson}}}
    ...
}
```

3) At the end of the processing, close the file and read it in:

```
\immediate\closeout\listoffoo
\input\jobname.foo
```

You'll have to define the commands like `\lessonfooline`.

Hope this outline helps.

Comment: Thanks! I found the `tocloft` package now, too. Requires even less code.

Comment: @pascal: you're welcome! `tocloft` seems to be a more high-level solution (which is better), my code is almost pure plain TeX.